# In calculating GCD in $\mathbb Z[i]$ does it matter if we switch $a$ and $b$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, gcd-and-lcm, euclidean-algorithm, gaussian-integers

I am trying to solve this problem:

Find the generator of the ideal $(47 - 13i, 53 + 56i).$ I know that I should use Euclidean Algorithm but I am wondering if it matters if I divided $a = 47 - 13i$ by $b = 53 + 56i$ or $b = 53 + 56i$ by $a = 47 - 13i$? and why?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can divide in either order because $\gcd(a,b) = \gcd(b,a)$.

Comment: You won't get a reduction to a "smaller" gcd problem if you don't choose the smallest argument as the divisor - just like for integers.  But that will be corrected in the next step when you swap the arguments. The same is true in any (algorithmic) Euclidean domain, e.g. for polynomials over a field- where the size measure is "degree".

Comment: @Brain I agree with Ethan's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use the Euclidean algorithm for ordinary integers you divide by the smaller (in absolute value) number in order to get a small remainder for the next step.

The algorithm would still work if you did it the other way since the first step would have a quotient of $0$ and a remainder the smaller number.

In the Gaussian integers you measure size using the norm.

Take it from there ...

Comment: Oh, thank you that is great!

Comment: The comment on the questoin is correct. I edited my answer to address it. @BillDubuque said the same thing in his comment there.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you, but is it **the** greatest common divisor or just **a** greatest common divisor that we will find i.e., is gcd unique or not?

Comment: It's _a_ gcd. In the integers $-3$ works just as well as $3$ for $\gcd(6,9)$. In the Gaussian integers you multiply any gcd you find by $\pm 1$ and $\pm i$ to find them all. The idea you will learn is "unique up to multiplication by a unit".

Comment: Perfect! thank you :)!

Comment: @Brain  Generally gcds are unique only up to associates (-= unit multiples in domain), see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2939562/242). The quotient and remainder in the Euclidean algorithm are unique only in a polynomial ring over a field (or a field), see  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/608281/242)

Comment: @BillDubuque thank you very much for the very detailed reply :)!